# How can I place blocks side by side?

Tags: blocks, theming

I found a solution to my question but the problem is I don't know where to insert this code. 
Is there a way to input this code through the site or do I need to go into the css files to do this?

http://www.drupalgardens.com/content/place-blocks-side-side

Basically the solution is to input code in the following manner:

```
#jayblock1  {
  float: left;
  width: 280px;
}
#jayblock2  {
  width: 280px;
}
#jayblock3  {
  width: 280px;
}
```

If there is an easier way to do this that doesn't require code I'd love to know!

Answer (score -1):

right, that is css code. It needs dots infront of the variables though:
.jayblock1

Here is an html with that css as an example...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
  .jayblock1 {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    background: red;
  }
  .jayblock2 {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    background: blue;
  }
  .jayblock3 {
    width: 280px;
    float: left;
    background: green;
  }
  div {
    height:10em;
    padding: 0.3em;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <div class="jayblock1">
    .jayblock1
  </div>
  <div class="jayblock2">
    .jayblock2
  </div>
  <div class="jayblock3">
    .jayblock3
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

check this for more on css floating:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you should paste this code in one of your theme's CSS files. If you have installed Firefox as browser, you should use Firebug to find the correct ID's or classes for your blocks. Also, I don't think your code will work. I think something like

```
#block-system-jayblock1,
#block-system-jayblock2,
#block-system-jayblock3 {
  float: left;
  width: 280px;
}
```

is what you're looking for.